# XSS in text-fields - PHP example

Tags: php, html, xss

Please consider this PHP page below, named xss1.php. You can upload it to any LAMP server or VM you have, to understand my conundrum.

```
<?php
ob_start();

session_start();

$searchValue = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
    $searchValue = trim($_POST["txtSearch"]);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>XSS: Sample 1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="xssForm" method="POST" action="xss1.php">
      <input type="text" id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" maxlength="128" value="<?php print($searchValue); ?>"/>
      <input type="Submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

I was under the impression, data in text-fields are displayed as is, and need minimal or no-XSS checking. In this text-field, If I were to stick in **<script>alert(1);</script>** and the form gets posted, the value gets displayed back in the text-field again, with no XSS execution or injection. I'm running Firefox 50.0.2. on my Mac OS X.

Now, if I stick in **"><script>alert(1);</script>**, there is XSS and I see a Javascript alert pop-out with 1 in it. The characters "/> come after the text-field, rendered as text on the page, not inside the text-field. What changed here? I'm a little perplexed and will perhaps spend the next hour trying to find the answer on XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet, at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

In Safari though, I don't see the Javascript alert pop-out, but "/> gets written outside the text-field, right after it on the page.

It's 2:01 am PT and I'm Sleepless in Seattle :)

Comment: Thanks @Keatinge, I was under the impression htmlspecialchars work when you want to render the text on the page, not for textfields where a string has to be displayed as-is, not processed by the script engine. That's the reason <script>alert(1);</script> did not execute before. I tried it now with htmlspecialchars in the text-field and that didn't get it to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was under the impression, data in text-fields are displayed as is, and need minimal or no-XSS checking

Your impression was wrong. Any user input into an HTML document needs to be considered for XSS. It must be either:

- Escaped
- Passed through a really good white listing filter
- From a trusted source (and that means trusted to not be malicious, and to write code without accidently writing something dangerous, and to not copy/paste code they don't understand).

> The characters `"/>` come after the text-field, rendered as text on the page, not inside the text-field. What changed here?

You added a `"` character. A `"` ends an attribute value.

Then you added a `>`. Inside a tag, but outside of an attribute value, a `>` ends the tag.

The `"/>` that were in the original document (i.e. the ones that are not part of the user input) no longer have an attribute and tag to close (because the `">` from the user input did that) so are rendered as text.